# Degenerate random variable and joint Gaussianity with any Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability

Can I claim that a degenerate random variable is jointly Gaussian with any Gaussian random variable since the linear combination of a constant with any Gaussian is always Gaussian?

Comment: Yes, you can, according usual conventions.

Comment: Yes, that would have a degenerate Gaussian distribution.